# Do P values have any meaning if they are more significant

Tags: statistics

Do P values have any meaning when they are below the significance value of 0.05 ?

For example, does a p value of 0.001 have more importance than a p value of 0.02. Many articles I have been reading are vague on this subject. Some say that the 0.05 does not have any meaning after it passes the significance threshold. However, in another paper, I read that you are more likely to make a type 1 error if your significance value is 0.04 than say a significance value of 0.01. Therefore this implies that a significance value does have some meaning when it is under the significance threshold of 0.05.

Can someone please clarify this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

P values basically measure the probability that, under the assumption that your hypothesis is false, your experiment still randomly gives you a result that appears to confirm your hypothesis as strongly as the result you got. As a small example, testing the hypothesis that there are more women than men by randomly selecting a single person and seeing that they're a women has a P value of 0.5 (or 50%), because under the default assumption that there are equally many of each, your selected person is 50% likely to be a woman.

This isn't the same as "the probability that your hypothesis is true," of course, but it is still a useful measure of your experiment's reliability. Therefore a lower p-value is always better: the lower the p-value, the less likely you are to be in the situation where you are wrong but think you are right.

The chosen threshold of p=0.05 has no particular significance, other than the fact that we need to have a threshold somewhere. Different fields use different thresholds depending on how easy it is to get significant results, which shows that the choice of 0.05 isn't set in stone. In a business environment, the p-value threshold might be chosen based on a cost-benefit analysis comparing the cost of further testing against the risk of being sued for a faulty product.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply. That was very helpful . However, I have been reading more, and it says that Neyman and Pearson suggest that if the p value is under 0.05 it doesn't have any more meaning than it being significant. Therefore, do they mean that 0.05 is no difference to 0.001 ? However, others suggest that a p value of 0.05 is more likely to get a false positive than a value of 0.01? These two contradict each other.